# __NSArrayM index beyond bounds

Tags: ios, arrays, indexing, crash, sigabrt

Sorry for the posting since similar questions have been asked many times.

I inherited an iOS app in Objective C and needs to revise it. Originally it worked fine in an older version of Xcode. Then I updated my Xcode and then it ran into an uncaught exception of array index out of bounds at the following method.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MartialArtsAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

The dump stack says that deep in the CoreFoundation framework, 
there is an index 3 to an NSMutableArray beyond bounds [0..1]. 
I am not sure what does that mean. I cannot see which array it is.

Besides, I don't see where I declared an NSMutableArray in the app. 
The dump stack is as follows. Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

```
2016-03-16 19:54:56.522 HanDynastyMartialArts[480:5616] WARNING: A Gesture recognizer (<UISwipeGestureRecognizer: 0x7ff9fa596790; state = Possible; view = <UIView 0x7ff9fa599c10>; target= <(action=upSwipeGesture:, target=<MartialArtsViewController 0x7ff9fb04ea00>)>; direction = up>) was setup in a storyboard/xib to be added to more than one view (-><UIView: 0x7ff9fa5af170; frame = (0 0; 320 450); autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7ff9fa5d77b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7ff9fa5af2d0>>) at a time, this was never allowed, and is now enforced. Beginning with iOS 9.0 it will be put in the first view it is loaded into.

2016-03-16 19:54:56.587 HanDynastyMartialArts[480:5616] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
*** First throw call stack:

    (

    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106658f65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165

    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001060d2deb objc_exception_throw + 48

    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010651ff55 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 901

    3   Foundation                          0x0000000105b11a11 -[NSKeyValueSlowMutableArray insertObject:atIndex:] + 106

    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106574432 -[NSMutableArray insertObjects:count:atIndex:] + 162

    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010657419f -[NSMutableArray insertObjectsFromArray:range:atIndex:] + 335

    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106574023 -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:] + 723

    7   UIKit                               0x0000000104c2e49f -[UIRuntimeOutletCollectionConnection performConnect] + 860

    8   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106599b10 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224

    9   UIKit                               0x0000000104967306 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864

    10  UIKit                               0x000000010475284d -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381

    11  UIKit                               0x0000000104753179 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178

    12  UIKit                               0x000000010475347c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 139

    13  UIKit                               0x0000000104796c26 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 54

    14  UIKit                               0x00000001047974dd -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 433

    15  UIKit                               0x0000000104797633 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 116

    16  UIKit                               0x0000000104798879 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 890

    17  UIKit                               0x000000010479967d -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57

    18  UIKit                               0x000000010493163d -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248

    19  UIKit                               0x000000010467911c -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 710

    20  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a55536a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146

    21  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a549bd0 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366

    22  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a549a4e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24

    23  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a53e1d5 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277

    24  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a56b9f0 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 508

    25  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a56c154 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92

    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001065849d7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23

    27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106584947 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391

    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000106579ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524

    29  UIKit                               0x00000001045c398d -[UIApplication _run] + 402

    30  UIKit                               0x00000001045c8676 UIApplicationMain + 171

    31  HanDynastyMartialArts               0x00000001042b3cbf main + 111

    32  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000106fae92d start + 1

    33  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1

    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the actual statement that is causing the error add an exception breakpoint:

1. From the Main Menu Debug:Breakpoints:Create Exception Breakpoint.
2. Right-click the breakpoint and set the exception to Objective-C.
3. Add an action: "po $arg1".

Run the app to get the breakpoint and you will be at the line that causes the exception and the error message will be in the debugger console.

[Breakpoint example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QB0L.png)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will try it soon after my current project is done.  Just too many things to do.

Comment: @FarnWang Consider accepting answers that are helpful. By accepting a answer you are indicating to future readers that it is a correct answer. To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Also please consider going back and accepting past answers, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities.

Comment: Thanks!  I will do the duty from now on.